# What does the '#1' mean in '/Content/LoremIpsum.xaml#1' of Modern UI for WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, modern-ui

I am looking into `ModernUI` these days and I have a little problem modifying my code. The problem comes from a `TabControl`. The sample from [`MUI DOC`](http://mui.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20predefined%20page%20layouts&referringTitle=Documentation) is like:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
  <mui:ModernTab SelectedSource="/Content/LoremIpsum.xaml#1" Layout="List">
    <mui:ModernTab.Links>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Lorem Ipsum 1" Source="/Content/LoremIpsum.xaml#1" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Lorem Ipsum 2" Source="/Content/LoremIpsum.xaml#2" />
    </mui:ModernTab.Links>
  </mui:ModernTab>
</Grid>
```

Can anyone explain to me the usage of `#1` in the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation is used the *fragment* navigation.  It means that when you use the selected source binding in your `ViewModel`, you can just simply parse out everything after the `#` to find your *`index`* of the tab selected. You have to listen to the event the type of `SourceChanged`, to know which tab was selected by the user or using the `OnFragmentNavigation` event.

For this purpose used the following code:

**`namespace FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation`**

`FragmentNavigationEventArgs.cs`

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides data for fragment navigation events.
/// </summary>
public class FragmentNavigationEventArgs
    : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the uniform resource identifier (URI) fragment.
    /// </summary>
    public string Fragment { get; internal set; }
}
```

**`namespace FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows`**

`IContent.cs`

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the optional contract for content loaded in a ModernFrame.
/// </summary>
public interface IContent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when navigation to a content fragment begins.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">An object that contains the navigation data.</param>
    void OnFragmentNavigation(FragmentNavigationEventArgs e);
    ...
}
```

**`namespace FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation`**

`NavigationHelper.cs`

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes the fragment from specified uri and return it.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">The uri</param>
/// <returns>The uri without the fragment, or the uri itself if no fragment is found</returns>
public static Uri RemoveFragment(Uri uri)
{
    string fragment;
    return RemoveFragment(uri, out fragment);
}

/// <summary>
/// Removes the fragment from specified uri and returns the uri without the fragment and the fragment itself.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">The uri.</param>
/// <param name="fragment">The fragment, null if no fragment found</param>
/// <returns>The uri without the fragment, or the uri itself if no fragment is found</returns>
public static Uri RemoveFragment(Uri uri, out string fragment)
{
    fragment = null;

    if (uri != null) {
        var value = uri.OriginalString;

        var i = value.IndexOf('#');
        if (i != -1) {
            fragment = value.Substring(i + 1);
            uri = new Uri(value.Substring(0, i), uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? UriKind.Absolute : UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }

    return uri;
}
```

Also you can see an example where it is used navigation together with the `IContent` interface in this question:

[Caliburn.Micro + MEF + Modern UI: IContent events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968090/caliburn-micro-mef-modern-ui-icontent-events)